# Exit while loop when it reaches the end of the excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, index-error

Hi I am new to python and was trying some codes to make my job easier. So here is my code

```
 counter = 0
 while True:

    row_values = worksheet.row_slice(counter+1,start_colx=0, end_colx=4)

    row['Dealer'] = int(row_values[0].value)
    row['Name'] = str(row_values[1].value)
    row['City'] = str(row_values[2].value)

    counter += 1

    if not row['Dealer']:
        break
```

I am trying to break the while loop when row['Dealer'] is null, that is when the end of excel file is reached. But it doesn't seem to work somehow. It keeps on giving **IndexError: list index out of range**. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks

Hi I edited my code to the following below:

```
   counter = 0
   while True:
    row_values = worksheet.row_slice(counter+1,start_colx=0, end_colx=30)
    row['gg'] = worksheet.cell_value(1+counter,1).strip()
    if not row['gg']:
        break


    row['Dealer'] = int(row_values[0].value)
    row['Name'] = str(row_values[1].value)
    row['City'] = str(row_values[2].value) 
    counter += 1
```

But the error is still the same! Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show which Python Module you are using and where `row` is initialized?

Comment: I am using xlrd module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: break the while loop when row['Dealer'] is null, that is when the end of excel file is reached.

You can get the end of Rows using `worksheet.nrows`, for instance:

```
import xlrd 
book = xlrd.open_workbook("myfile.xls") 
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0) 
print("Sheetname:{0} Rows:{1} Columns:{2}".
    format(sh.name, sh.nrows, sh.ncols)) 

# Iterate all Rows
row_value = {}
for rx in range(sh.nrows): 
    print(sh.row(rx))
    row_value['Dealer'] = sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=0)
    row_value['Name'] = sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=1)
    row_value['City'] = sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=2)

    # Break before end of Rows at first Empty Cell
    if row_value['Dealer'] == '':
        break
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the solution however i was still wondering why i was not able to break the while loop!

Comment: @Shubzumt: Maybe the Cell isn't empty, check for Blanks or not printable character. The Cell after `sh.nrows` don't get into account!

Answer (score 1):

The [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)  library is a great choice for working with Excel.

Install pandas with pip.

```
pip install pandas
```

Install xlrd (needed for working with Excel files).

```
pip install xlrd
```

From there you can read the excel spreadsheet with the following.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('your_excel.xlsx')
```

df is now a DataFrame object. You can analyze and transform the data using the available pandas tools.
Full documentation for [read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: Actually you don't need to install specifically xlrd. This comes with pandas pip...